# Pandas read_csv, erro UTF-8. Formato diferente do csv

Tags: python, pandas

estou tentando ler um arquivo csv através de um dataframe `pd.read_csv('MGP.csv')` e estou tento o seguinte erro.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 72: invalid continuation byte
```

Tentei também incluir o parametro  `encoding='utf-8'` e aparece o mesmo erro. Quando eu coloco `encoding='latin-1'` ou `encoding='ISO-8859-1'` aparece o seguinte erro:

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 3, saw 2
```

Não sei se faz alguma diferença, mas o formato do CSV que estou recebendo do sistema é bem dirente, veja abaixo:

```
"   P   r   o   c   e   s   s   o   "   ;   "   D   e   s   c   r   i   ç   ã   o   "   ;   "   I   D       C   o   m   p   r   a   d   o   r   "   ;
"      2   0   2   3   3   "   ;   "   S   E   R   V   I   Ç   O       D   E       I   N   T   E   R   V   E   N   Ç   Ã   O              S   U   B   S   T   I   T   U   I   Ç   Ã   O       D   E       C   O   M   P   R   E   S   S   O   R   "   ;   "   2   5   2   3   9   "   
   "   2   0   2   4   5   "   ;   "   P   e   s   q   u   i   s   a       -       N   E   G   O   C   I   A   Ç   Ã   O       -       P   e   s   q   u   i   s   a       Q   u   a   l   i           N   o   s       "   ;   "   4   4   7   4   5   "   ;
```

Sabem com eu consigo resolver esse problema e importar para um dataframe normalmente?
Obrigado

Comment: tentou usar o argumento `sep=';'`?

Comment: Também já tentei, com o `encoding='latin-1` ele carrega o dataframe, mas com os nomes da coluna escrito Unnamed: 0, Unnamed: 1 etc, e o conteúdo completamente vazio

Comment: pode disponibilizar o arquivo?

Answer (score -3):

Caso queira ignorar as linhas que ocorrem o erro de parsing, pode fazer:

```
data = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', error_bad_lines=False)
```

Pode ser um problema com os delimitadores ou com alguma linha em especial. A fim de resolver, procure especificar os argumentos `sep` e `header` quando tu chama o `read_csv`. Um exemplo:

```
data = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', sep = ';', header=0)
```

O caracter que não é lido é o "ç", assim, outro meio de resolver seria a substituição do "ç" por "c". Depende do âmbito do problema.